# How to refresh table data ajax form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm submitting an ajax request using Bootstrap Modal. When I submit, I want to refresh the modal body. It means that what I have saved from my form I'm showing my modal body I want show that row in table. when I use this, that table got hidden without refreshing. What's wrong?

```
$('#uploadform').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('task_id','{{$task->id}}');
    formData.append('title',$('#title').val());

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{{url('/uploadTask')}}',
        data:formData,
        success:function(data){

            $("#images-table").html(data);

            $("#some_form")[0].reset();

        },
        error:function (data) {
            alert('error');
        },
        async:false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    });
});
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Also never ever use `async:false` ... it is a terrible practice. Look at the deprecation notice it creates in your console

Comment: i took of  async:false, but still its hide that div when i submit a form

Comment: There isn't enough information to provide an accurate answer.  You need to verify the ajax response payload is actually being returned in the format you'd expect, then you need to bind the data to your table.  If you're not using something like angular, that means iterating over all the elements in the response and adding tr and td elements to build your table.

Answer (score 0):

return that row data form controller and create html and append to to existing table. there is no concept of refreshing bootstrap table. only append new data.

```
$('#tableid').append('<tr><td>name</td><td></td></tr>');
```

this will append that row to at the last of your table.